# Why is cucumber loading support code?

Tags: javascript, cucumber

I have to say that this is probably the craziest problem I have EVER had and I just cannot understand it. I have a class; it's called `dashboard.js` and it resides inside of my `test/features/support` folder. Here's the contents:

```
'use strict';

class Dashboard {
  constructor(browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
  }

  viewGame(id) {
    return this.browser.get(`/dashboard/game/${id}`);
  }

  getTeamName(color) {
    return browser.findElement(By.model(`game.teams.${color}.name`)).getAttribute('value');
  }
}

module.exports = Dashboard;
```

I am using protractor to run my cucumber tests. All of my tests involved worked perfectly fine on another machine and I have not altered them since I loaded them on this machine. There is no difference between the machines; both are running the exact same version of IOJS in the exact same environment.

Running my tests gives me this error.

```
[launcher] Error: TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'
  at Object.Dashboard (c:\loluk\test\features\support\dashboard.js:4:14)
  at c:\loluk\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:62:25
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Object.wrapper (c:\loluk\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:59:15)
  at Object.initializer (c:\loluk\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:20:37)
```

Removing the `require` from my test code to this support file does not solve the issue; Cucumber still loads it. I have no configuration telling it to load ANY support files. So, naturally, I change the folder from `support` to `lib`. This should fix the problem - right? It's not named support, after all.

```
[launcher] Error: TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'
  at Object.Dashboard (c:\loluk\test\features\lib\dashboard.js:4:14)
  at c:\loluk\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:63:25
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Object.wrapper (c:\loluk\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:60:15)
  at Object.initializer (c:\loluk\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:21:41)
  at Object.Library (c:\loluk\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\support_cod
```

Nope. In fact, no matter what I rename this file, or it's folder, it will always load itself, despite me never telling Cucumber to do so. What's even stranger is Cucumber is not only loading it, but then trying to call it for some reason. This means that for whatever reason it is attempting to execute my class - it did not do it on another machine.

Does anyone know how I can convince this ruddy cucumber to behave? Only by moving the files OUT of the `features` folder is this problem solved, but I don't understand why it is loading code

- I haven't asked it to
- It didn't do on another PC
- It shouldn't be loading because it's outside of the step definition folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand two things. The first is this:

`$ cucumber.js --help` extract:

```
-r, --require LIBRARY|DIR     Require files before executing the features. If
                              this option is not specified, all *.js and
                              *.coffee files that are siblings or below the
                              features will be loaded automatically. Automatic
                              loading is disabled when this option is specified,
                              and all loading becomes explicit.

                              Files under directories named "support" are
                              always loaded first.
```

Second thing is: when Cucumber *loads* a file for you, it will check whether whatever is exported by that file is a function or not. If it is, it will be executed automatically. This is what allows for step definitions to be declared within a simple function (`module.exports = function () { this.Given(...) }`). If one of your files exports a class constructor, it will be executed by Cucumber (without the `new`keyword) as well, leading to potential issues.

The simplest fix is to export that class as a property of `exports`, like so:

```
module.exports.Dashboard = class ...
```

Obviously, you need to change the require statement a bit:

```
var Dashboard = require('./path/to/dashboard.js').Dashboard;
```

Another way to fix things is to explicitly use the `--require` flag on the CLI, as explained in the help.

Comment: It seems very counterintuitive to have to require something in order to disable loading.